# Variable not storing values over ssh

Tags: linux, awk, ssh, redhat, cut

I need to run some commands over ssh to a remote machine.
But while trying to execute some basic commands such as:

```
ssh abc@remotemachine.com "a='hello'; echo $a"
```

produces no output on the screen.
However

```
ssh abc@remotemachine.com "echo 'hello'"
```

is working fine with the output

```
Hello
```

can anyone explain me why this is happening ?

Also now the major issue is that I need to execute awk/cut onto the remote machines and store there outputs in a variable.
Something like :

```
ssh abc@remotemachine.com 'a=$(df /tmp | awk 'NR==2 {print $NF}');echo $a'
```

But I am unable to place **'** inside **'** **'** .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ssh abc@remotemachine.com  'a="hello"; echo $a'` will be fine
in your command, $a will be interpreted in local shell, before execute ssh.

an other way is ssh abc@remotemachine.com "a='hello'; echo \$a"

Comment: Thanks. It worked but can you provide a detailed explanation of the same. 
Also, what if you want to use cut or awk inside the ssh statement. The ' in those commands won't let them execute..
For e.g 
 ssh abc@remotemachine.com 'df /tmp | awk 'NR==2 {print $NF}' '

Comment: have a look : https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/how-to-print-an-apostrophe-%27-in-a-shell-script-using-awk-644719/

Comment: Not satisfying my use-case . Also cn you explain why this is happening,
Considering ssh abc@remotemachine.com "echo hello" works fine.

Comment: In single quotes, no escaping is possible. There is no way how to include a single quote into single quotes.  you can do this way: ssh abc@remotemachine.com "df /tmp | awk 'NR==2 {print $NF}' "

Comment: I actually want to store the result in a variable for further processing (I've a restriction of using one command only)
ssh abc@remotemachine.com " " doesn't allow me to store output in a variable as I mentioned in my question

Comment: @VatsalPrakash, i update my answer too, please have a look.